# How to await a subscribe in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

my question is very simple... Consider the following angular method:

```
fillOrderHeader() {
    let rows3:Array<OrderHeader>= new Array<OrderHeader>();
    this.orderService.getAllOrdersHeaders().subscribe(headerList=>{
      headerList.forEach(headerDoc=>{
        headerDoc.get().subscribe(header=>{
          let headerMetadata:OrderHeader= new OrderHeader();
          headerMetadata.clientName= header.data().clientName;
          headerMetadata.agencyName=header.data().agencyName;
          rows3.push(headerMetadata);
        });
      })
    });
    return rows3;
  }
```

How to await to subscription before to return a `row3` array?

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to convert the observable to a promise, there is an rxjs operator for this, and await the result. Then use `await` _instead of_ the `.subscribe`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Ok, how?... Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`async`/`await` can only work with `Promise`s. So to make it work in your example, you'll have to change your `Observable`(s) into `Promise`(s).

Good thing though is, you can simply use the `toPromise` API on an `Observable` for doing that.

Another thing that you'll have to do is declare your `fillOrderHeader` function as `async`. To do that you'll have to `await` the calls to `this.orderService.getAllOrdersHeaders().toPromise()` and `headerDoc.get().toPromise()`

Try this:

```
async fillOrderHeader() {

  let rows3: Array<OrderHeader> = new Array<OrderHeader>();
  const headerList = await this.orderService.getAllOrdersHeaders().toPromise();

  for(let headerDoc of headerList) {

    const header = await headerDoc.get().toPromise();

    let headerMetadata: OrderHeader = new OrderHeader();
    headerMetadata.clientName = header.data().clientName;   
    headerMetadata.agencyName = header.data().agencyName;

    rows3.push(headerMetadata);      
  }
  return rows3;
}
```

Comment: I think the return statement won't wait for the forEach to finish..you may need a traditional for loop.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Fixing. Thanks.

Comment: The code not works... header.data().clientName-> error.. the property "data" no exists in the type "Promise<DocumentSnapshot>"

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to put an `await` for this line: `await headerDoc.get().toPromise();` Try it again please. I've updated the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
async fillOrderHeader() {
   let rows3: Array<OrderHeader>= new Array<OrderHeader>();

   let headerList = await this.orderService.getAllOrdersHeaders().toPromise();
   for(let headerDoc of headerList){
       let header = await headerDoc.get().toPromise();
       let headerMetadata: OrderHeader = new OrderHeader();
       headerMetadata.clientName  = header.data().clientName;
       headerMetadata.agencyName = header.data().agencyName;
       rows3.push(headerMetadata);
   }

   return rows3;
 }
```

Comment: its good write a few words about your change what and why. Our brains aren't comparers :D